# Retrieving last customer name from history table with no timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following two tables:

customers:

```
|Customer Code|Current Customer Code|
|123456|-|
---------------
|123455|-|
---------------
|123454|-|
---------------
|123453|-|
---------------
```

History:

```
|customer Code x (current)|Customer Code y(former)|
|123456|123455|
---------------
|123455|123454|
---------------
|123454|123453|
---------------
|123453|123452|
---------------
|123452|      |
```

What I want:

```
|Customer Code|Current Customer Code|

|123456|123456|
---------------
|123455|123456|
---------------
|123454|123456|
---------------
|123453|123456|
---------------
```

At this moment the current customer is unknown in the customer table. I need to retrieve the current customer code from the history table and write this to current customer field in the customer table.

I came as far as this:

```
SELECT 
[Customer Code], [Current Customer Code] FROM customers
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT 
    c.[Customer Code],
    t.dats
    FROM Customers c
        inner JOIN (
            SELECT [Customer Code x], [Customer Code y] FROM 
            history t
            LEFT JOIN Customers c
            ON t.bpid = c.[customer code]
       ) t
   ON c.[Customer Code] = t.[Customer Code]
```

A few notes:

- There can be multiple sets of customers, but these sets will in the history table.
- There can be jumps in the numbers, for example from 12455 to 12453.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start. I don't understand at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: Retrieve the latest current customer from the history table while looking at the history. So the current customer code for the customer is 123456. While the history of customer codes goes back to 123453. In my customer table I want to set the value of current customer code to that latest customer code for the history of these customers (In the example: 123456 through 123453)

Comment: That's great. I can't help without some details. And from you posted I don't think you have much chance anyway because you have nothing the data posted to indicate what the current customer might be. Post some table definitions and sample data. Then try to explain what you want.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a single customer or multiple customers? Also, if you start with a number, what's the expected result? Another number? Example, please?

Comment: Do you want to update ALL customer, to set the current ID?

Comment: All customers that were former current customers, so for customers 123453-123456, but not for 654321-654325, which would be a different set with its own history.

Comment: Sean Lange, I will improve the question with proper data when I can, I don't have acces to a computer currently.

Comment: Post your desired output based on the sample data that you've provided, please.

Comment: Somewhat improved my question. All I can do from phone now, will improve when I have acces to a computer.

Comment: Seems fairly simple. But I assume you have the same customer row in the history table more than once. How do you know which one you want? There is nothing to indicate order? And you are trying to update the entire customer table with this new value? That sounds like something is pretty off in the design if you have the same value in every row of the customer table.

Comment: 2 questions: Numbers can jump downwards? Do you have an ID that represents a group of customers?  i.e. Customer X = 123456, Customer Y = 123456, ID = 1000 and this ID will be the same for every customer code change for that customer?

Comment: They can jump downwards, and sadly I don't have an ID that signifies the same customer over different codes. I start to feel I should ask the client to supply a more useful set of data.

Comment: @sean, I agree. It is however all I am supplied with currently. If I had an ID which is the same for the set of customer id's it would make life easier.

Comment: Yeah given the requirements and the data you are stuck with an impossible task.

Comment: I dunno if it is impossible.  Nothing is impossible, just not everything is feasible haha. If you could do it manually, then so can a computer imo. What about if you think of the data as hierarchy?  So pull all the customers where [X] = [Y] and this will give you your "Parent" row.  Then treat all the other rows as children and traverse the hierarchy but I do not know how big your table is to know how expensive this would be.

Comment: A table has no natural order so there is no last.

Comment: Updated question as data for history table was wrong. Customer Code and Current Customer Code are not the same for any row in the history table.

Comment: is there *ANYTHING* else in these tables? (an auto-incrementing ID for example)

Comment: @Used_By_Already Sadly there isn't...

Answer (score 1):

[[ANSWER UPDATED - To account for OPs revised source data]]

@PreQL mentioned treating the data like a hierarchy.

I've declared a couple of table variables here for an easy cut/paste/test of the query...

```
declare @customers TABLE (CustomerCode int, CurrenctCustomerCode int)

insert into @customers values (123456, null)
insert into @customers values (123455, null)
insert into @customers values (123454, null)
insert into @customers values (123453, null)

declare @history TABLE (CustomerCodeX int, CustomerCodeY int)

insert into @history values (123456, 123455)
insert into @history values (123455, 123454)
insert into @history values (123454, 123453)
insert into @history values (123453, 123452)
insert into @history values (123452, null)
```

We need to find the anchor point for the hierarchy - and we can do that with a subquery that finds the trade ids that aren't 'prior' ids for subsequent trade ids.

```
   select c.* 
     from @customers c 
left join @history h 
       on c.CustomerCode = h.CustomerCodeY  
    where h.CustomerCodeX is null
```

Putting the subquery with the into my original CTE looks something like this:

```
; with cte (CCX, CCY, CCC) 
as
(

    select h1.CustomerCodeX, h1.CustomerCodeY, x.CustomerCode
    from @history h1
    join (select c.* from @customers c left join @history h on c.CustomerCode = h.CustomerCodeY  where h.CustomerCodeX is null) x
    on h1.CustomerCodeX = x.CustomerCode
    union all 
    select 
        h.CustomerCodeX,
        h.CustomerCodeY,
        cte.CCC
    from @history h
    join cte on h.CustomerCodeX = cte.CCY
)
select CCX as CustomerCode, CCC as CurrentCustomerCode from cte
```

Output:

```
CustomerCode CurrentCustomerCode
------------ -------------------
123456       123456
123455       123456
123454       123456
123453       123456
123452       123456
```

Hope it's useful.

Comment: hahaha ahh I just got home and got around to dealing with this.  That's exactly what I was going to post :p, +1

Comment: I was thinking of something like this! I just didn't have the knowledge/skill to get there. I'm going to try and see if it works well for the full dataset.

Comment: Oh no... I got the history table wrong. I'm sorry. I updated it in the question. There is no case where Customer Code and Current Customer Code are the same, apparently.

Comment: @PreQL - sorry to steal your thunder ;-)

Comment: Hahaha, not a problem,  all is fair in comments and answers :p

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a recursive CTE.

My query starts with all actual customer codes that do not have a newer customer code in the history. Then, it recursively adds the former customer codes using the history (except the empty one).

```
WITH
  cte (FormerCustomerCode, CurrenctCustomerCode) AS (
    SELECT actual.CustomerCode, actual.CustomerCode
    FROM customers actual
      LEFT JOIN history newer ON actual.CustomerCode = newer.CustomerCodeY
    WHERE newer.CustomerCodeY IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT older.CustomerCodeY, newer.CurrenctCustomerCode
    FROM cte newer
      INNER JOIN history older ON newer.FormerCustomerCode = older.CustomerCodeX
    WHERE older.CustomerCodeY IS NOT NULL
  )
UPDATE customers
  SET CurrenctCustomerCode = cte.CurrenctCustomerCode
FROM customers c
  INNER JOIN cte ON c.CustomerCode = cte.FormerCustomerCode;
```

The recursive CTE creates a list like this:

[image: CTE Result]

This list is then used by the UPDATE statement to update the customer table (adjust the MAXRECURSION option if required).

Comment: Oh no... I got the history table wrong. I'm sorry. I updated it in the question. There is no case where Customer Code and Current Customer Code are the same, apparently.

Comment: The first line in your sample history is stille the same (mapping a code to itself), and now you seem to have changed the order of old and new customer code (X and Y). Which one is the old and which is the new customercode in a history record? Please update the question again.

Comment: Sorry, for that, updated the question again. First column is current, last column is former.

Comment: Thank you, now I was able to shorten my answer a bit. :-)